Missing wildfly version in new server dialog box
I have downloded eclipse oxygen 2018, Wildfly 27 and JDK 22. I want to make dynamic web project,
when, I try to create new server it only shows Wildfly  till 12 not 27.
when I try to make server with wi 12 and start it , it give error JDK not supported. I have already installed Jboss tools

Eclipse Oxygen is 7 years and 25 releases old, try with the actual current Eclipse 2024-06 which understands Java 22.

WildFly 27 is also quite old. WIldFly 32.0.1.Final is the latest and WildFly 33 is about to be released.
